# Azure SDK + Django + Visual Studio 2012 - Publish to Azure succeeds, but I get 500 error

Tags: django, azure, python-2.7, visual-studio-2012

I followed the instructions here: 
https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/python/tutorials/django-with-visual-studio/

However, whenever I try to open the url to my web app in the cloud I get a 500 error.

The tutorial doesn't mention setting up the TEMPLATE_DIRS setting in the django application or doing any work on the cloud service machine to install python/django.  Could these be the problem?

Comment: Try providing more detail - for example, attach your settings.py file. TEMPLATE_DIRS should be a list of path names that contain the templates for your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple error here.  I had installed a python module locally that was getting imported by the django project.  This module wasn't added as part of the automatic deployment to Azure.

Fix was to enable remote desktop for the Azure machine, and install the python module.

The most useful debugging tool was to visit the website via the local IP after I was remoted into the Azure machine.  The link for the site is in the IIS site settings.  This bubbled up the python errors instead of the generic 500 error.

Hope this helps someone else!